# How to wrap / float text around a rectangle shaped div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap or float some paragraphs around a div. Do to using a CMS the elements are reordered with flex order to move the grey box down if that makes any difference. I've tried shape-outside, floating divs, removing the P tags and using SPANS but nothing works at all. I added shape-outside CSS to the .quote-wrapper element and .quote-wrapper:before. Its just stacked. I don't really see JS as a solution either. This is all dynamic content so adding a fixed height to the grey box is not an option. A max width would probably be okay though. The P tags are added to the paragraphs automatically also.

[image]

```css
.column-quote-content-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .quote-wrapper {
    order: 3;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
  p {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  p:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  p:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  p:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 4;
  }
  p:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column-quote-content-inner">
  <h3>Morbi Aenean Curabitur</h3>
  <div class="quote-wrapper">
    <p class="quote-content">"Donec leo massa, varius non rhoncus a, finibus sit amet odio."</p>
    <p class="quote-name">Aliquet Tristique</p>
  </div>
  <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id lorem sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras sed est id justo iaculis lobortis. Etiam tincidunt condimentum tellus.
    Phasellus sed lorem in magna condimentum blandit. Suspendisse eget ligula scelerisque, laoreet mi in, mattis lorem. Vestibulum aliquet sollicitudin eros vel faucibus. Mauris eu elit a sem fermentum posuere in ut turpis. Mauris vulputate, nisl nec
    fringilla blandit, lacus dolor facilisis enim, id viverra risus neque vel neque.</p>
  <p>2 Morbi eget urna nunc. Proin ac pharetra justo. Nunc in lacus hendrerit, dapibus orci id, sodales arcu. Aliquam fermentum risus eu justo convallis imperdiet. Morbi ut urna at augue hendrerit dictum. Aliquet Tristique In vulputate nunc non orci convallis
    facilisis. Curabitur in felis malesuada, volutpat felis quis, vestibulum ante. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  <p>3 Integer accumsan neque et mollis eleifend. Fusce laoreet interdum magna, in pharetra diam. Donec leo massa, varius non rhoncus a, finibus sit amet odio. Morbi non dolor pulvinar, egestas tortor et, lacinia libero. Mauris nec luctus dui. Nulla facilisi.
    Duis sodales ante et nunc pulvinar facilisis. In neque lorem, pretium vitae est at, porta maximus dolor. Aenean aliquet enim non est tristique, in fermentum risus tempor.</p>
  <p>4 Morbi neque nibh, ornare sed auctor at, placerat in magna. Nunc at nulla eros. Sed tempus at eros at commodo. Donec a eleifend velit. Integer ut tincidunt massa. Aenean sed pulvinar dui, convallis facilisis purus. Nullam tortor risus, maximus nec
    tincidunt non, gravida ac neque.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should post your css too if you have tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,

I am using the shape-outside CSS property to get this effect.

For more information, refer this [CSS Shapes](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/)

Also refer this https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside for browser support

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.parent {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.parent span {
  shape-outside: content-box;
  margin-top: 200px; /*can be adjusted as per your design*/
  max-width:400px;
  float: left;
  shape-margin: 40px;
  margin-right: -68px;
  position: relative;
  left: -90px;
  background:grey;
  padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span> "Donec leo massa,  varius non rhoncus a, finibus sit amet odio.""Donec leo massa,  varius non rhoncus a, finibus sit amet odio.""Donec leo massa,  varius non rhoncus a, finibus sit amet odio."</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos
    sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga
    laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero
    repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a
    aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione
    rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus
    sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos,
    earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita,
    facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae
    dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos
    sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga
    laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero
    repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a
    aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione
    rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus
    sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos,
    earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita,
    facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae
    dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dignissimos sapiente fuga laboriosam libero repudiandae a aliquam. Ratione rerum soluta voluptatibus sequi dignissimos, earum dicta expedita, facere molestiae dolor sunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is looking promising. I don't understand why the P tag content wraps up above the grey box ? How is that working? For me its still stuck under the grey box. It doesn't wrap up above and around.

Comment: @user2593661 ,it wraps because of the shape-outside property, and also change the margin top value of the box

Comment: Yes this works. I had display flex on the parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.quote-wrapper { 
  float:left; 
  margin-left:-200px; 
  margin-right:15px; 
  margin-bottom:15px; 
  padding:10px; 
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.column-quote-content-inner {
  margin-left:215px;
}
```

Maybe margins may help?